# Store refresh token in a cookie

Tags: botframework, direct-line-botframework

I am initializing the chat through a token obtained calling to DirectLine Api (POST/v3/directline/tokens/generate). I store this token in a cookie and use it to resume a conversation.
My problem is that the direct line automatically refreshes the token after 30 minutes and I didn't find a way to save the new token.
Does anyone know how I can save the new token?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subscribing to *conectionStatus* of DirectLine enables listening for **ConnectionStatus.Online** which is fired after **ConnectionStatus.ExpiredToken**.  Then, update the cookie:

```
directLine.connectionStatus$.subscribe(connectionStatus => {
    if (connectionStatus === ConnectionStatus.Online) {
      setTokenCookie(this.token);
    }
  });
```

Reference DirectLineJs source:
https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-DirectLineJS/blob/master/src/directLine.ts#L473

```
 public reconnect(conversation: Conversation) {
        this.token = conversation.token;
        this.streamUrl = conversation.streamUrl;
        if (this.connectionStatus$.getValue() === ConnectionStatus.ExpiredToken)
            this.connectionStatus$.next(ConnectionStatus.Online);
    }
```